# Setting presets with operator menu (precise)

Tags: python

Not sure if this question is blender related or pure python.
Please let me know if this is pure python. I will delete this question here and ask it on PythonStack.

I am using the presets function in the OOTB operator dialog.

What I notice in the preset files is that it writes back my presets but adds extra numbers to it. I guess this happens because the property is a float property.

This is the entry that is saved.

```
op.test = 0.010287000797688961
```

This is how it supposed to be

```
op.test = 0.010287000000000000 (10.287 mm)
```

Is there a way to make sure the presets will be precise?
Since it is being written using the preset function I don't know if a simple python code can fix this.

Comment: Similar to another recent question, float supports only 8 digits of precision. I suggest using a `StringProperty` and storing the value as a string, then parsing it at runtime when you need it with `float(value)`

Comment: @Gorgious sorry for pedantism, float32 supports 24 binary digits of precision, and for the most part it can be represented in 8 decimal digits, but to guarantee the number is fully recovered when converted back to float32 you [need 9 decimal digits](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1251). Also note the number is truncated to 8 significant digits (results in 5 s.d. due to 3 zeroes), rather than rounded, which would produce `0.010287001`. Probably an implementation quirk, which limits the precision for UX purposes...

Comment: It's also worth to note that [usually](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) trying to save `0.010287000797688961` as float will result with `0.010287000797688961029052734375` being stored (`00111100001010001000101011001111` in memory), while `0.010287` is a different float `0.01028699986636638641357421875` (`00111100001010001000101011001110` in memory)